# Negative votes on newest questions

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I just scrolled down the 50 newest questions.  Probably MORE than half of those have a -1 and just even reading the titles I don't think there is reason.  Is there a single person doing all these?

Is there a max down votes per day?  if not there should be.

Comment: All you did was look at the titles to decide if they were -1 worthy or not? So if I write an acceptable title that says (for example) "How do I setup Outlook with Gmail", and the body contains (only) the same text, that's not worthy of a -1 for a lack of research effort?  :)  Anyhow, we all have a max number of votes per day (up or down). Next, let's try to explain to how new questions that _suck_ often get a +1 vote.  ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 nah I looked a bit deeper than that, but not a first... I was so alarmed at the number of -1's that I did post here pretty fast, but I think DragonLord got it right in his answer.

Comment: You have a few examples? Because there are a good amount of low quality questions on the front page.

Comment: @Ramhound it's past history... you can't go there now and see the straight column of -1's... To be honest it looked like vandalism... DragonLord saw it.. he get's what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 6):

After reviewing some of these questions, I've noticed that while many of these questions are unclear or off-topic, some of the downvotes are indeed without merit.

**I think [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) is to blame for this**. See [this hat](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/red-shirt):

[image: Description of the Red Shirt hat]

> ### Red Shirt
>
> cast 5 downvotes on posts that are later deleted or closed

It seems people are downvoting marginal but valid questions in an attempt to get this hat.

Comment: Yea I hadn't noticed that hat.  Encouraging down votes tho is a bad thing I think.   Bad questions will get them without the encouragement xD

Comment: I'd add they need to be put on hold or deleted. I'll prolly go through those, close the ones that deserve it, and upvotes the one that deserve it. Cause hats people :/

Comment: This was a really stupid and destructive thing to do as part of the hats definitions.  The definitions need to be better reviewed in the future or SU should refrain from participation.

Comment: There's a few of them that seem stupid like that. Like "Go delete you own answer" or "delete X comments from 2014".

Comment: I think the problem is *people* (aka *users* in some circles). I got a red shirt by reviewing posts from some of these people, and I'm happy to hand out downvotes to those who deserve it, whether I get a hat (or shirt) or not. At the end of the day, incentives or not, users will still be users.